# Where is conda.pth?

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

As I understand it, `conda develop \path\to\project`  adds a path to a file called `conda.pth` which stores all the paths accessible to python. I would like to find this file so I can check which paths I have added to it.

Where can I find this file? I am using a Windows machine.